# How to use previous key detail to upload updated APK on play store?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, apk

While updating the previous apk on playstore i got to know i need previous key details. I some how managed to find it . now my problem is how to use the previous keystore to upload the updated apk.

Comment: Make your question clear first.

Comment: i followed this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version) . There is a step **I can't find the original keystore anywhere**  .i have found the original keystore and now i dont know how to use this original(previous/first keystore). or what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **android studio** goto

> Built -> Generate Signed APK..

.

specify key file

give password then click on next it will generate APK file

upload it on play store.

If you are using **eclipse**

then follow steps

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing-eclipse.html

Comment: this link is to upload for first time . But i have to update the app that is already on the play store.i have previous keystore value but i dont have password of this previous keystore. so tried generating new keystore. evrything was good untill google said different signature. i have thrigh many links.

Comment: select radio button of **use already existing keystore** 

but password is necessary.

Comment: i did this but i dont have the password related to the previous keystore . now what??

Comment: then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371724/lost-keystore-password

but not sure , it will work

Comment: i am going through this link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97479/discussion-between-uttami-and-gaurav-polekar).

Answer (score 1):

To sign your app in release mode with extisting keystore in Android Studio, follow these steps:

1. On the menu bar, click Build > Generate Signed APK.
2. On the Generate Signed APK Wizard window, click Create new to create
   a new keystore.
3. **If you already have a keystore, go to step 5**.
4. On the New Key Store window, provide the required information as
   shown in figure

**Your key should be valid for at least 25 years, so you can sign app updates with the same key through the lifespan of your app.

[image]

5. On the Generate Signed APK Wizard window, select a keystore, a
   private key, and enter the passwords for both. Then click Next.
6. On the next window, select a destination for the signed APK and click Finish.

[image]

Generated apk is located at path specified in filed of 'APK Destination Folder'

**Reference** : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio

**Note** : If you are using Eclipse please check below link as well below steps :

1. Select the project in the Package Explorer and select File > Export.
2. On the Export window, select Export Android Application and click
   Next.
3. On the Export Android Application window, select the project you
   want to sign and click Next.
4. On the next window, enter the location to create a keystore and a
   keystore password. If you already have a keystore, select Use
   existing keystore, enter your keystore's location and password, and
   go to step 6.

[image]

5. On the next window, provide the required information as shown in
   figure 5. Your key should be valid for at least 25 years, so you can
   sign app updates with the same key through the lifespan of your app.
6. On the next window, select the location to export the signed APK.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing-eclipse.html

Thanks..!!

Comment: i appreciate your help but i need for updating the app on play store.this link is for uploading the apk first time

Comment: @ uttami : For updating application you just need to change version and do same steps as mentioned ..!!

Comment: i did but still problem remains the same

Comment: @ uttami : What is the actual problem ? Are you getting any error while uploading apk to play console ?