# How to enabling Google Play App Signing without keystore password

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-app-signing

This question is not duplicate because, this question is regarding Google Play App Signing, answers mentioned in the other question doesn't solve this question.

I have an active app on playstore with **500,000+ downloads**, I have backed up my keystore file but **unfortunately I forgot my keystore password**, is there any way I can **Enable Google Play App Signing**, upload my new apk & release new version.

I tried all ways to find the keystore password but no luck.

Comment: You don't have the keystore configuration details in your gradle file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a lost KeyStore password in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/how-to-handle-a-lost-keystore-password-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

> unfortunately I forgot my keystore password

This is a problem that has come up many times. If you have lost the password, you cannot use the keystore. You can, however, use brute force apps on the password to crack it. But that may take a while. IF oyu have a "standard" password you used/use a lot, try using this/these passwords and see if that is the right one.

So, without the password you cannot do anything - not enable google play app signing, and you cannot sign it yourself.

And a tip for the future: Write down the password, or use one you know you will remember. The password doesn't have to be very complex, personally I don't even understand why there is a password. But when you have lost the password you have two options (after trying different possibilities): Brute force it or create a new keystore and upload your app as a new one.

Without the keystore password, you cannot use Google Play App signing or sign it yourself. SO you need to get a hold of that password

Or you can see if it is in a temporary gradle file at this location:

```
..Project\.gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin
```

---

[One brute force option](https://github.com/rsertelon/android-keystore-recovery)

[SO question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149530/forgot-keystore-password-thinking-of-brute-force-detection-will-it-corrupt-the)

[one SO question on losing the keystore password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/how-to-handle-a-lost-keystore-password-in-android)

[another SO question on losing the keystore password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371724/lost-keystore-password)